# Type of files created in a blackberry project

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I created my first Hello world project for BlackBerry and following files were created in the **deliverables** folder:

```
 - HelloWorld.cod
 - HelloWorld.cso
 - HellowWorld.debug
 - HelloWorld.jad
 - HelloWorld.jar 
 - HelloWorld.rapc
```

What is the purpose of each of these files? I know at least that the jar file must be deployed as a mobile application. But what about all other files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .cod file is basically BlackBerry's proprietary version of the .jar file.  (This is usually the version downloaded from the App Store.)

The .cso file is a helper file used when signing the application. (It says which keys are needed.)

The .debug file is a helper file used when running the application in the debugger.

The .jad file describes the application to help the device know if it's compatible. (If you were downloading onto a BlackBerry from a website instead of the App Store, this is the file you'd point your link at, which would contain the path to the cod/jar.)

The .jar file is the main application file for MIDP, which is sort of a generalised mobile java runtime environment.

The .rapc is a helper file used by the BlackBerry JDE when it's compiling/building the project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive explanation.